# Find the chromatic index of a cycle $C_n$ for each $n$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I am trying to solve the following question but I am confused where $\chi^{'}(G_n)$ comes from and how to go about solving for each $n$.  I know that the chromatic number of a $C_n$ where $n > 1$ is 3 for odd $n$; 2 for even $n$. Or does my following attempt to part (a) work and can I apply a similar approach to part (b)? Thank you for your help.

Let $G_n$ be the graph with vertices $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ and edges

$E = \{x_ix_{(i+1) \bmod n}, x_ix_{(i+2) \bmod n} : 1 \le i \le n\}$

(i. e. a cycle $C_n$ with edges added between all pairs of vertices two apart.)

(a) For each $n$, compute $\chi(G_n)$.

(b) For each $n$, compute $\chi^{'}(G_n)$

===========
Here is my answer for (a) :

We will proceed by induction. Consider the $C_n$ defined above. We claim that $\chi(G_n) = n$  for all $n$. \

The case where $n = 3$ is trivial. So for our base case, we will consider $C_n$ such that $n = 4$, which gives us a $K_4$. We know that $\chi(K_n) = n$ for any \textit{n} (as we covered in lecture that if $G$ contains an $m$-clique then $\chi(G) \ge m$). See the graph below where $\chi(G_n) = n$:

// here I draw a $K_4$ each *n* in a different color.

For our inductive step, let $G = C_n{+1}$. We see that since $C_n$ defined as above constructs a $n$-clique for any \textit{n}, we always get $\chi(G_n) = n$. See the graph where $\chi(G_n) = C_5$.

// here I draw a $C_5$ every node having a different color.

We see that this holds for $\textit{n = 5}$ as well as every $\textit{n}$ where $n > 5$.

Answer (score 1):

For the part (a):

If $n \leq 5$, then $\chi(G_n) = n$. For $n \geq 6$, we have that if $n \equiv 0 \pmod 3$, then $\chi(G_n) = 3$ (it's just color $1, 2, 3$ alternately). If $n \equiv 1, 2 \pmod 3$, it's easy to prove that $3$ colors are not sufficient. Probably there is an explicit construction, but you can use Brook's theorem to prove that $\chi(G_n) = 4$.

Comment: Thank you. I will edit my attempt accordingly. COuld you also tell me what the $\chi^{'}(G)$ is? I mean we did not take out any nodes from the graph or anything, where does it come from?

Comment: It is the edge chromatic number, i.e, the minimum number of colors that are necessary to color the edges of the graph such that there are not adjacent edges with the same color.